# CouchDB view collation issue

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I have a problem with my couchdb view. First some code:

Here is the view

```
free: {
    map: function (doc) {
        if (doc.type == 'application') {
            emit([doc._id, 0], doc)
        } else if (doc.type == 'client') {
            emit([doc._id, 1], doc)
        } else if (doc.type == 'release') {
            emit([doc._id, 2], doc)
        } else if (doc.type == 'department') {
            emit([doc._id, 3], doc)
        } else if (doc.type == 'ticket') {
            if (!doc.assigned && doc.priority) {
                emit([doc.applications, doc.clients, doc.release, doc.departments, 4], doc)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The fields applications, clients and departments are usually arrays.

When I call the view, I get this as result

```
{
    "total_rows": 9,
    "offset": 0,
    "rows": [
        { "id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae930010b5", "key": [ null, null, null, null, 4 ], "value": { "_id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae930010b5", "_rev": "1-46c0118a029d2adefc377ac31ae548b2", "ticketnumber": "asdasdasd", "priority": "12", "description": "asdasd", "deadline": "20.10.2014", "minutesperweek": "50", "ordervolume": "50", "impactdescription": "asdasd", "type": "ticket" } },
        { "id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93001f31", "key": [ "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93001f31", 0 ], "value": { "_id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93001f31", "_rev": "1-04098bc81ec5a337f96eab6096fcb022", "name": "Info", "type": "application" } },
        { "id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae930024b0", "key": [ "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae930024b0", 0 ], "value": { "_id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae930024b0", "_rev": "1-2da7e9fccb85de5d7d334075d64005f4", "name": "AP", "type": "application" } },
        { "id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93004bf0", "key": [ "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93004bf0", 3 ], "value": { "_id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93004bf0", "_rev": "1-e4cb8f4d61b6664eca9ee33cf8490223", "name": "Test", "type": "department" } },
        { "id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93005100", "key": [ "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93005100", 0 ], "value": { "_id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93005100", "_rev": "1-cfc8610af75c99d29a20698b9568c51d", "name": "Test", "type": "application" } },
        { "id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93005a89", "key": [ "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93005a89", 0 ], "value": { "_id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93005a89", "_rev": "1-56d590eaa45aa073b17b51ec304c0222", "name": "test", "type": "application" } },
        { "id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93006306", "key": [ "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93006306", 1 ], "value": { "_id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93006306", "_rev": "1-5886b6d2c6a7f52e3e99b12ead71e0b7", "name": "Test", "type": "client" } },
        { "id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93006cb5", "key": [ "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93006cb5", 2 ], "value": { "_id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93006cb5", "_rev": "1-2cd31bf6ada650c899cb021ef8149f90", "name": "Test", "type": "release" } },
        { "id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93007c88", "key": [ "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93007c88", 3 ], "value": { "_id": "c36cb356c3aa10617ee687ae93007c88", "_rev": "1-33c62380b66a045ed4e8f386a19edc86", "name": "asd", "type": "department" } }
    ]
}
```

What bugs me about this, is that it emits all applications, clients and departments even, if there is not any of these in my ticket.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I think your use case is a bit unclear. From the code you've presented, everything seems to work OK.

Comment: @Mariusz I think, I just had a misthought. I added a reduce function, that nulls everything what isn't a ticket. And then I can sort the nulls out :)